# Как обойти словарь python и соеденить строки в переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

возможно задача тривиальна но все же подскажите если знаете. Есть словарь типа:

```
dict = {'text1': '12345', 'text2': '67890', 'text3': '12345'}
```

Простым циклом:

```
for key in dict:
    print(dict[key])
```

я вывожу значения:

```
12345
67890
12345
```

Как образом циклом:

```
for key in dict:
    print(dict[key])
```

добавить все значения value поочереди в переменную content (сохраняя перенос строки)
я понимаю что нужна конкатенация строк или что то в этом роде но не могу понять как.

Большое спасибо за советы

Comment: мне очень интересно, как вы получили из этих данных свой список ключей

Comment: да извините - я немного вытащил из контекста

Comment: втащите обратно, иначе совершенно непонятно, как из одного словаря получить несколько одинаковых ключей

Comment: еще раз извините - я поправил - вопрос как соединить строки в переменной

Comment: Или нужно что-то похожее на это `['12345\n', '67890\n', '12345\n']`?

Comment: Оставлю здесь для коллекции `d1 = {'text1': '12345', 'text2': '67890', 'text3': '12345'}`
`l1 = [val+"\n" for val in d1.values()]`
`print(l1)`

Comment: есть json и на основе его вывода необходимо конкатенацию - https://ideone.com/Nr6Avw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так. Кстати, не стоит называть переменные именами стандартных типов - можно получить неожиданные ошибки

```
d = {'text1': '12345', 'text2': '67890', 'text3': '12345'}
var = '\n'.join(d.values())
print(var)
```

---

в связи с комментарием. всё так же

```
import json

var = json.loads(var)
res = []
for i in var['fields']['description']['content']:
    for i in i['content']:
        for key, value in i.items():
            if key == 'text':
                res.append(value)
res = '\n'.join(res)
print(res)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо что откликнулись, розверну все же вопрос, есть json и на основе его вывода необходимо сделать конкатенацию: https://ideone.com/Nr6Avw

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо - все получилось!